# Search icon moving out of div, works fine in chrome but not in mozilla

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have a simple search bar which contain a div and inside that div there is - 
input element for text and search button.

```
       <div className="search-box">
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder={PLACEHOLDER.search}
            value={this.state.search}
            onChange={this.updateSearchBar}
            onKeyUp={this.keyPress}
          />
          <IconButton className="search-icon-button" onClick={this.handleSearchIcon}>
            <SearchIcon />
          </IconButton>
        </div>
```

Css file -

```
.search-box {
border: 1px solid black;
width: 200px;
height: 30px;
display: flex;
min-width: 180px;
margin-right: 2%;
padding-left: 1px;}

.search-box input{
    width: 100%;
    color: black;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}
.search-icon-button {
    color: #FF7D50 !important;
    padding: 3px 0px 0px 7px !important;
}
```

IconButton and SearchIcon are material ui component.

Below I am attaching the screen shot of chrome and mozilla.

**Chrome -**

[image]

**Mozilla -**

[image]

Could you please help I have used width: webkit-mozilla but I want this to work fine on both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give browser specific css.You can give padding according to set search icon.I hope it will helps you.

```
@-moz-document url-prefix(){
   .search-icon-button {
    color: #FF7D50 !important;
    padding: 3px 0px 0px 4px !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: But I think the problem comes from that icon is getting outside the div width only.
Without **search-icon-button** css selector also it should be inside that div.